# Laravel is this respond time ok?

Tags: laravel, performance, laravel-5, optimization

I noticed some major slowness inside my laravel application. Even a basic route without any middleware or any operation takes around **250ms** to load, on localhost. So i thought  it's a bit crazy slow. What are your thoughts ? Is it because of my computer's performance ? Or it would get faster when i deploy it on a server ?

SPECS:
laravel 5.7
Vagrant, Laravel/homestead (parallels, 6.4.0)

EDIT:
More through details about timing:
[image: Timing]

Test sample on the same environment but, newly created laravel 5.7 project. Project only has one controller and one basic method to return a variable which is `$test=microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START;`. 
Result is usually around 130~ ms. Considering  that my actual application was returning view with some libraries and style sheets, it's pretty decent.

Conclusion for now: I guess this speed is totally fine for my local environment (considering pc specs and vagrant without nfs).

---

**Edit 2:**
As @Tarasovych suggested, i did disable  debugbar and used `$test=microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START;` to get the response time. Results as follows:

**Without debugbar:**

```
$test=microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START;
```

$test is:

For initial, first call to the route: 500~ ms.

For refresh on the same route: 190~ ms.

**With debugbar:**

```
$test=microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START;
```

$test is:

For initial, first call to the route: 530~ ms.

For refresh on the same route: 200~ ms.

So roughly, debugbar affect respond time by approx. 10~ ms. 
Maybe I should've also disable the app_debug in .env too ?
I Haven't tried that yet.

If I didn't provide enough information, please let me know so I can update.

Thanks

Comment: You can try enabling NFS and see if it works for you. It made my Homestead a little bit faster. See [this](https://tech.osteel.me/posts/2016/01/19/how-to-enable-nfs-on-laravel-homestead.html)

Comment: @Mozammil Thanks for the reply, i'll try it now. But does nfs really do change project infrastructure ? Or exploit any security issues ?

Comment: I am not sure about that, sorry :)

Comment: For a dev environment, response times look ok. For production, they should be better. But it depends a lot on what you are using, what you are caching (routes, config, ...) and the overall workload. At this point, I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: @Namoshek Thats a relief to hear that !  And is it possible to make some estimations on how much faster it would be when deployed ? Maybe through your experiences with older projects.

Comment: I'd imagine that vagrant adds some overhead to your response times. You might want to try running your project locally with docker as it doesn't have the overhead of VMs. Laradock is a good place to start.

Comment: What's inside `Queries`? How longs does it take? P. S. Note, that debug bar need some time to profile all Laravel work.

Comment: @Skywarth It is really hard to tell how much of a performance gain you can get. It depends on a lot of things and normally there are still tools available to make it faster, even if it is already. So you will have to define what's acceptable first.

Comment: @Tarasovych Good markdown on that, it was something to get user's details after the login. I tried without login(which mean no query execution) didn't affect the response time, only a few ms.

Comment: @Skywarth try to measure response time with and without debugbar.

Comment: @Tarasovych Added report according to your suggestion. Please do review it , thanks.

Comment: @Skywarth have you cached your routes and config?

Comment: @Tarasovych After you mentioned, i've cached my route and config. It changed the performance a bit like 15~ms.

Comment: I think it's ok. 200ms to 300ms (usually) is the base time for booting an sending the respose. the only challenge you'll face in performance is your response data size. in most cases the only reason is the response data size

Comment: Thread can be closed. I changed my operating system to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and hooked up a SSD. Now it's almost incredibly times faster. Usually it took around 500 ms. But now 10~20 ms. I think the major change was caused by OS. Because i was using vagrant and homestead on Windows. Thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For a development environment, this is acceptable. This isn't great performance for a production environment.